# form().bindFromRequest() with array values

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have a `<select name="items" multiple>` in the front end, and I'm using `form().bindFromRequest()` in the backend, then using a DynamicForm.

But here's the hiccup:

```
DynamicForm form = form().bindFromRequest();
form.field("items").value(); // Only return one value !
```

How can I get all the submitted value? without having to go through `request().body().asFormUrlEncoded().get("items")` if possible.

Comment: Have you figured this out? I'm in the same boat and I cannot get the all multiple selection option to show up in the controller.

Comment: I finally used the `request().body().asFormUrlEncoded().get("items")` option :/

Comment: Same problem here and it's so annoying that Play2.0 forced us to use models to get form data.

Comment: They don't force you to use models to get form data, you can use a DynamicForm or directly the request(). (Or you can also make your own class and copy the DynamicForm class, by including multiple values)

Comment: Did you find a way to use bindFromRequest() with array fields?

Comment: I'm sorry but it's been years since I have touched PlayFramework so I won't be of any help here :/

Answer (score 4):

Binding array values require to properly name value in request. Param name should end with "[]" to be bound as an array (List) value.

In your HTML you should have:

```html
<select name="items[]" multiple>
```

In Form class add it as:

```java
public class ExampleForm {
    public List<Integer> items;
}
```

I know this not solve DynamicForm problem, but it is far more elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks.  Worked for input as well.